# Is it a bug to pass a single-element array to SendInput?

Tags: winapi, sendinput

Given the following code

```cpp
void foo() {
    INPUT input{};
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
};
```

is it a bug to pass a single-element array to [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) in consecutive calls? This seems to be perfectly supported by the documentation.

Comment: The question could be renamed to "How to correctly send a sequence of input events with SendInput?" because it is essentially what answer is all about.

Comment: @VTT: Yes, it could be. But that's not the question that gets asked. The question that gets asked over and over again is the one, that's in the title. Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742660/c-execution-causes-monitor-to-disconnect#comment80434590_46742660).

Comment: The question title should be easier to find for users struggling with such issues and looking for help. I think that more generic title variant would be easier to discover. Passing `2` or `3` or `4` as a first argument could be a potential bug too if input sequence is supposed to be longer. So title just about passing `1` is too narrow.

Comment: @VTT: Then they are looking for a different question, not this one.

Comment: @BoltClock It seems that the point of this question is to cover a *common* case of `SendInput` misuse when users split input sequence sending into several `SendInput` invocations.

Comment: There is a [ongoing meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357835/whats-primarily-opinion-based-about-the-question-does-this-code-exhibit-a-b#357835) about this question. It would be good if all the discussions could happen there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: Maybe.

Longer answer: It depends.

To see what it depends on, and when this matters, it helps to understand, why [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) was introduced into the Windows API: For one, it consolidates the [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx) and [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx) APIs into a single API call. More importantly, it adds a significant feature that isn't available to the previous calls. This is called out in the documentation:

> The **SendInput** function inserts the events in the [**INPUT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270.aspx) structures serially into the keyboard or mouse input stream. **These events are not interspersed with other keyboard or mouse input events** inserted either by the user (with the keyboard or mouse) or by calls to [**keybd_event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx), [**mouse_event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx), or other calls to **SendInput**.

In other words: `SendInput` establishes atomicity of injected input sequences, irrespective of external events outside the control of the calling code.

It is usually important to atomically inject input, when the input consists of a sequence of individual events, like in the question. The code injects a mouse button down followed by a mouse button up in 2 individual calls to `SendInput`. While the intention is to have a single mouse click event, the implementation allows other input sources to intersperse input. When another input source produces a mouse move event in between the mouse button down and up events, the intended click has turned into a drag-and-drop operation. Instead of selecting a file in File Explorer, that very same code has thrown the file into the Recycle Bin. That clearly constitutes a bug.

Likewise, injecting keyboard input consisting of key combinations generally requires atomicity guarantees. Injecting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> requires all four input events to be in a single transaction. Otherwise, a (malicious) input source could synthesize a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key up event right after the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down, leaving the code injecting a <kbd>C</kbd>, with a stray <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key up event trailing. That's probably not what was intended either.

In summary: It is a bug to call `SendInput` repeatedly, passing `1` as the first argument if the following conditions are true:

- The input consists of a sequence of individual input events.
- The input is required to be interpreted as a single unit.

Comment: This answer is just unnecessary verbose rehearsal of documentation.

Comment: @VTT: Is it? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8021954/1889329) would disagree with not being necessary. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438156/1889329). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11438677/1889329), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23203944/1889329), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31606962/1889329). In fact, pick *any* random `SendInput` question, and you'll see, that this Q&A is dearly needed.

Comment: It could be shortened considerably, basically "If you are sending a sequence of input events and don't want other events getting in-between you must send the whole pack with a single call to `SendInput`."

Comment: @VTT: This is a Q&A site for everyone. If you believe you can do better, go ahead and submit your own answer.

Comment: I have checked and double checked many times that this supposed atomicity of `SendInput` is completely false. If `SendInput` is called right when a key is auto-repeating (i.e. the user is holding a key down), the auto-repeating key will be intermixed with the characters injected by `SendInput`.

Comment: @get I cannot comment on test code I cannot see, nor on the presumed implications or consequences.

Comment: @IInspectable, I know and I'm sorry for that. I'll post a question showing the problem and I'll link it here.