# How do you make a typing macro in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to make a program that when you type "Alt+A" it will write type out a line like "Hello" for example. This is the closest I've gotten:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(65))
{

    cout << "worked" << std::endl;  
    string bind = "Hello";

    INPUT Input = { 0 };
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    for (int i = 0; i < bind.length(); i++)
    {

        Input.ki.wVk = VkKeyScanA(bind[i]);
        SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));
    }
    Sleep(500);
}
```

It works similar to how I want, but there are some problems that I encountered:

- I can't get the Alt key to work. When I use GetAsyncKeyState(18), it runs the "worked" output but it doesn't type out any of the word.
- Whenever I press the key bind (for example "A"), it will type that letter as well. Is there any way I can cancel out that key press? I was thinking that I could just make it so that it types the backspace button before the word, but I'm assuming there is a better to go about this.
- I also have a problem that the program doesn't type exactly what is put in. It doesn't type capital letters, and it only types one letter if there are two in a row. In the code that I put, it will say "helo" instead of "Hello."

Comment: Just a quick terminology issue, the word "[macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html)" in the title threw me off. It means something very different to some C++ developers :)

Comment: I saw that when I was looking up how to make this. Should I switch up the wording? Typing Bot or Script instead?

Comment: Also, you appear to be using the `std` namespace, this can [lead to problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1265092/1357841). Apologies that I'm answering all the issues you aren't asking and not the one you are ;)

Comment: I wouldn't change the wording, just something to be aware of!

Comment: The tutorial I used for SendInput used it. I usually go without it.

Comment: Your question should mention (and possibly tag) the library that you are using. Without a system-specific library, C++ has no concept of "keyboard" or "key press".

Comment: [RegisterHotkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) is one way, but you need a window handle to receive messages.

Comment: *"it only types one letter if there are two in a row"*, Because you only send keydown (0) and no keyup (`KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`) for each character.

Comment: You'll need to unlearn everything you learned from the tutorial, that taught you how to use `SendInput`. `SendInput` allows you to inject a series of input *atomically* into the system. It was introduced to solve the issue with `keybd_event`, that cannot do this. Plus, the return value of [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) encodes several pieces of information. The implicit conversion to `bool` drops all of it. Time to read the documentation.

Comment: What would you recommend using instead of SendInput? Also before I tested if GetAsyncKeyState was equal to -32767, but I saw people use it as a bool.

Comment: [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate): *If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.* -32767(0x8001): the key is down, and the key was pressed after the previous call to `GetAsyncKeyState`. 0x8000 and 0x8001 are both equal to true.

Comment: The high-order byte of [`VkKeyScanA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscana#return-value) return value contains the shift state. If it is a capital letter, the shift bit will be set to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some simple changes to your code, which can basically meet your needs.
But if you need higher functionality, you may need to use [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey), and create your window to handle the `WM_HOTKEY` message.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)0x001E0BF2; //notepad window
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(18)&0x8000)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(65)&0x8000)
            {
                INPUT keyup_ALT = { 0 };
                keyup_ALT.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                keyup_ALT.ki.wVk = 18;
                keyup_ALT.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &keyup_ALT, sizeof(INPUT));

                cout << "worked" << std::endl;
                string bind = "Hello";

                INPUT Input[2] = { 0 };
                Input[0].type = Input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                Input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                for (int i = 0; i < bind.length(); i++)
                {
                    short ch = VkKeyScanA(bind[i]);
                    Input[0].ki.wVk = Input[1].ki.wVk = ch;
                    if (((ch & 0xff00) >> 8) & 0x1)
                    {
                        INPUT shift = { 0 };
                        shift.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                        shift.ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;
                        SendInput(1, &shift, sizeof(INPUT));
                    }
                    SendInput(2, Input, sizeof(INPUT));
                    if (((ch & 0xff00) >> 8) & 0x1)
                    {
                        INPUT shift = { 0 };
                        shift.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                        shift.ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;
                        shift.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                        SendInput(1, &shift, sizeof(INPUT));
                    }
                }
                Sleep(500);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

CHANGES:

1. Add status check of ALT key;
2. Make the return value of the GetAsyncKeyState and (&) 0x8000;
3. Make the ALT key up, to resolve ***"it runs the "worked" output but it
       doesn't type out any of the word."***
4. Check the return value of `VkKeyScanA`, the high-order byte contains
   the shift state, which control the capital letters, then determine whether to send shift key.

Comment: [That's not how you are supposed to use `SendInput`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46744894/1889329).

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks for the reminder. I didn't write before because of lack of time.