# Use pointers in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I need to use "CreateTimerQueueTimer" to create a timer.

The parameter must be pass as pointer.

Here my code:

```
void sendKey(int vk, ) {

    KEYBDINPUT  kb = { 0 };
    INPUT       Input = { 0 };
    int scan = MapVirtualKey(vk, 0);

    /* Generate a "key down" */
    kb.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
    kb.wVk = vk;
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki = kb;
    Input.ki.wScan = scan;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

    /* Generate a "key up" */
    ZeroMemory(&kb, sizeof(KEYBDINPUT));
    ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    kb.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
    kb.wVk = vk;
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki = kb;
    Input.ki.wScan = scan;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

    return;
}


void CALLBACK ProcessRequests(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    sendKey((int)lpParameter, true);

}


void myfunc()
{
    int VirtualKey=50;

    CreateTimerQueueTimer(&m_hTimer, nullptr, &ProcessRequests, &VirtualKey, 100, 0, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE);
}
```

Inside "ProcessRequests" there is the function "sendKey" that accept integer as parameter but lpParameter is a pointer. How I can pass the value of "lpParameter" and convert it in integer ?

Thanks !

Comment: you probably can't store a pointer in an `int`, the former is generally 64-bits and the latter is generally 32-bits

Comment: For C-style callbacks that pass a `void*` (a.k.a. `PVOID`) for user data, you must `static_cast` the parameter back to the appropriate type (`int` in this case).  Which you are already doing.  So what specific problem are you having with this code?

Comment: Note that you've got undefined behaviour here, since the fimer may be fired when `VirtualKey` is gone. You either nees something that survives until the timer callback is called or in this scenario you could pass the value as `intptr_t` cast to `void*`: `CreateTimerQueueTimer(..., std::bit_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(VirtualKey)), ...);` `sendKey(static_cast<int>(std::bit_cast<intptr_t>(lpParameter)), true);` and not worry about the lifetime of any value pointed to...

Comment: My app is windows In my log I see " ProcessRequests: 190831599" where 190831599 is lpParameter, but I need  the value and not the pointer. I need to use "static_cast" ? Thanks !

Comment: with "static_cast<int>(std::bit_cast<intptr_t>(lpParameter)" not compile but with "static_cast<int>(std::_Bit_cast<intptr_t>(lpParameter)" compile but the result is 190831599 and not the value.

Comment: On a side note: [Is it a bug to pass a single-element array to SendInput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744894/)

Comment: int VirtualKey=50; declare this as a global variable or static variable (to make the variable a long term lifetime) , then in ProcessRequests, call it as: sendKey( *(LPINT) lpParameter,  ...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this:

1. `lpParameter` *points to* an `int`, but you're treating it as if it *is* an `int`
2. The `int` pointed to by `lpParameter` is local to `myfunc` and therefore no longer exists by the time your timer fires and your callback gets called

The first issue is simple to solve, just change the way you interpret `lpParameter`:

```
void CALLBACK ProcessRequests(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    int* param = static_cast<int*>(lpParameter);
    sendKey(*param, true);
}
```

The latter issue is a bit tougher, and how you solve it will depend on your needs.  Since it looks like these functions are all members of some class (based on the name of `m_hTimer`), you may want to store the key code as a class data member instead of a local variable in `myfunc`:

```
class MyClass
{
    int VirtualKey;

    // ...

    void myfunc()
    {
        VirtualKey = 50;  // set the class member instead of
                          // creating a local variable

        CreateTimerQueueTimer(
            &m_hTimer,
            nullptr,
            &ProcessRequests,
            &VirtualKey,
            100,
            0,
            WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE
        );
    }

    // ...
};
```

If the functions aren't part of a class or you don't want to keep any sort of global state that multiple calls to `myfunc` could interfere with, then another approach would be to dynamically allocate the parameter.  Just remember to free it when `ProcessRequests` is done with it:

```
void CALLBACK ProcessRequests(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    int* param = static_cast<int*>(lpParameter);
    sendKey(*param, true);
    delete param;
}

void myfunc()
{
    int* VirtualKey = new int(50);

    CreateTimerQueueTimer(
        &m_hTimer,
        nullptr,
        &ProcessRequests,
        VirtualKey,  // NOTE: no &, VirtualKey is already a pointer
        100,
        0,
        WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE
    );
}
```

I would recommend the former approach if possible.  It would be easy to create memory leaks if you forget to free the key code in some code path (i.e. if you later add code to cancel the timer before it runs).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` an `int*` pointer that points to a local `int` variable, but then you are treating `lpParameter` in `ProcessRequests()` as-if it were the `int` value instead of the `int*` pointer that it really is.

Passing the `int` *value* into the callback is fine, but you need to pass th value *type-casted* to a pointer, eg:

```
void CALLBACK ProcessRequests(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN /*TimerOrWaitFired*/)
{
    sendKey(static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(lpParameter)), ...);
}

void myfunc()
{
    int VirtualKey = 50;

    CreateTimerQueueTimer(..., reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(VirtualKey)), ...);
}
```

---

Also, calling `SendInput()` 2 times with 1 `INPUT` at a time without any delay in between the calls [is a logic bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744894/) in your code that will likely cause issues with the input queue. Since there is no delay in your code, you should instead call `SendInput()` 1 time with 2 `INPUT`s, eg:

```
void sendKey(int vk, ... ) {

    INPUT Inputs[2] = { };
    ...

    /* Generate a "key down" */
    Inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = ...;
    Inputs[0].ki.wVk = ...;
    Inputs[0].ki.wScan = ...;

    /* Generate a "key up" */
    Inputs[1] = Inputs[0];
    Inputs[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    SendInput(2, Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```